Construction of Dirichlet multinomial from independent negative binomials
I have a dataset with ISO3 country code, Year (from 2010 to 2019), Causes of death category (24 categories in total) and number of deaths. The sum of deaths across causes is fixed. My goal is to predict the expected number of deaths for each country/cause combination for the period 2020-2023.
My idea was to run independent negative binomial regression models for each country/cause combination using gam function in R because there is clearly overdispersion in my data :
for (i in unique(df$iso3)) {
  
  for (j in unique(df$cause)) {
  
  whichs <- which(df$iso3 == i & df$cause == j)

  temp <- df[whichs, ]

  model <- gam(deaths ~ s(year), data = temp, family = nb(theta = NULL, link = "log"))

  pred <- predict(model, se.fit = TRUE, type = "response", newdata = data.frame(year = c(2020,2021,2022,2023)))

  }

}


To make sure that the sum of deaths across causes add up to the known and fixed total, it seems I need to construct a Dirichlet multinomial from those independent negative binomials. See this reference: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.04343 "A Dirichlet-multinomial distribution is equivalent to a collection of independent negative binomial distributions with the same scale parameter conditioned on their sum". Is it the right way to go?
If so, I am not sure what I need to do in R to apply this. I tried different theta values in the code below but the sum of deaths across causes does not add up to the fixed Total + setting a defined theta value affects the model fit.
model <- gam(deaths ~ s(year), data = temp, family = nb(theta = **NULL**, link = "log"))

What should I do? A simple way has been to rescale the expected number of deaths by causes so that the sum across causes matches the fixed total but I would like to do things properly.
